# Which location would be better for my this type of room to install split air conditioner?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I'm from north India. I have to install a split air conditioner ([see example](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B08R918D6Y?tag=web_gadgetshow_seealso-21&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1)). So I'm wondering what location in my room would be better.

My room dimensions are roughly 10 x 12 x 10 (Length x Breadth x Height *in feet*) and a rough diagram is below:

[image]

The window glasses are not permanent (I mean I can open the window glasses).

The space between roof and doors/windows top is about 2 feet.

Now I would like to know which wall would be better for indoor AC unit?

I read a similar answer [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/68874/what-is-the-best-place-to-install-an-air-conditioner-in-a-room), but I quite didn't get it. Especially what the user meant by *heat loss and gain*.

Further, I've heard people that you should not put AC near Windows or Doors as it will affect cooling. And some say above windows is very good choice. I'm really confused.

Personally, I felt that the red wall would be good place, but I'd give it a little less preference (**but still I would like to know your view about it**) to it if there's any other better location for it in this room. Because red wall is adjacent to my neighbor's home, so the pipe *can't* cross that wall. Also, I'd prefer the outdoor unit at roof.

**So is there any better location overall?**

*(Please let me know if any other details are needed)*

Comment: Is there already an electric supply for it?  If not are you going to run one on the surface or through the wall?  Where from?  Where will the outside part be?  Assuming the wall with the window is an outside wall, will the outside part be right outside there?  Is there room for the unit above the window?  I would put it above the window if it can fit there and if getting the power and coolant lines there are possible.

Comment: I understand the electric supply part. But let's assume it can reach any corner. I just need to what are usually ideal options.

Comment: When you are talking a split it sounds like a mini split correct?  Although mini splits are quiet they do make some noise and in heat mode a little bit more at times, the solid wall may be the best option for noise if it is an exterior wall as far as location of the outside unit if it is used for both cooling and heating it will not matter. If only cooling in a shaded area or wall. If majority heating in a sunny location. I like mine in the center of the room not blowing on me, some like that so opinion comes into play also. Choose an easy to wire and install location in the room / outside 1st

Comment: @EdBeal I've just added example of the AC in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heat loss or heat gain is how fixed heating is installed. What that means to keep a uniform temp in the room we put registers under / over windows . Where the outside temp affects the room more.

I don’t find mini splits following this quite as much possibly because there air discharge is 3-5x the area of a fixed vent and the minis usually have active vents that oscillate further turning the air in the room. By conventional setups you might want the mini over the window. Will your mini fit there it has to have room to open you have to clean the filter regularly.

Installing over a window may have you drilling the line set through a header not so easy and the lines and drain go down to the outside unit so now it needs to be off set from the window and that looks out of balance to me I would rather put it on the red wall and use the furniture and visual how it looks to mount it. So heat gain and loss with small fixed registers makes sense but with mini’s that big thing on the wall if not located in a way that it looks balanced it can negatively affect resale later.

Comment: I just wonder what has to do with heat gain or loss here. I have to cool my room to 20 degree Celsius from 48 degree Celsius.

Comment: I still don't understand those words "It is best to install the indoor unit near the area of maximum heat loss and gain" in the other question's answer. I'm not good at English.

Comment: The unit being installed on the area or wall that is warmest or coolest it is that simple. I tried to explain.

Comment: okay. But I don't understand why installing it on coolest or warmest would be same?

Comment: I think you assumed my AC both cools and warms the room? Note my AC is for summer use only, only to cool room.

Comment: So suppose, if it's too hot. The hot wind comes from my window. So it makes sense to install it near window so it makes it cool. Right?

Comment: For fixed vents that is the conventional wisdom. For a mini split that has a larger vent that can sweep across an area on a wall 90 deg from that wall may make an easier better looking install and work well. Without the room layout with furniture it is hard to say but highest heat load is not always the best place.

Comment: Actually there's no furniture other than those 2 3 things I've mentioned in diagram. Just a bed and table + chair. Also, could you please explain "out of balance" meaning?

Comment: Visual balance, placing a inside unit not in the center of a wall or centered over a window when offset up on the wall the balance of a room is altered and it ends up affecting resale in some cases furniture in the room can create a balance but even untrained eyes notice things are not quite right if out of balance or unequal placed in a space.